# irreducibility of a polynomial over $\mathbb{F}_2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

Is there any criterion (theorem or algorithm) to find out a given polynomial $f(x)$ is irreducible over the field $\mathbb{F}_2$?

Comment: Are you asking because you have a specific exercise? Do you want to be able to do this sort of problem by hand?

Comment: No! It is not an homework. I want to use this on a computer program to solve another problem.

Comment: You can factor all polyonomials over a finite field into irreducibles using Berlekamp's algorithm. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berlekamp%27s_algorithm, or Knuth part 2.

Comment: When the given polynomial has rather '"small" degree, there are some other sneaky methods. Is that the case? Or do you assume the degree to be arbitrary large und you want the best algorithm working for any case?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do it is to try to factor it with [Berlekamp's Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berlekamp%27s_algorithm). Unfortunately there isn't much anything better than that.

Comment: Berlekamp's algorithm is very good, you don't really need anything better than that. ;)